# What is the coffee script equivalent of () => { return test() }

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

So basically I'm trying to write this in CoffeeScript and I am just stuck...

```
this.helpers({
    parties: () => {
        return Parties.find({});
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean you want code in coffeescript that compiles to that exact javascript?

Comment: `parties: () -> Parties.find({})` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.helpers(
    parties: () -> Parties.find({})
)
```

produces

```
this.helpers({
  parties: function() {
    return Parties.find({});
  }
});
```

Not sure if there's a way to make coffeescript compile to ES6 (i.e. use ES6 arrow functions) but that code is functionally equivalent to what you want